# jquery onclick run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run all onclick events on page load.
how can I do something like this:

```
$('.upload').foreach(function(){
 //execute onclick for found element (ex: test(this, 'var') )
});

<div class="upload" onclick="test(this, 'var')">text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to give you a 'this will take some work' answer, but it is considered bad practice to use onclick events these days. Since you are already using jQuery, I would recommend using one of jQuery's event binding utilities to replace your onclicks.

`.click()`, `.delegate()`, `.live()` and `.bind()` will all be helpful in this.

However...

Also since you're using jQuery, you just need to fire `.click()` on them if you're really not interested in bringing your code up to current standards. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) methods to do that.

```
$('.upload').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7srCQ/) of it work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
$('.upload').each(function(){
   $(this).click();
});
```

But there is probably a better solution to whatever you are trying to achieve.